# How to set theme setting

Tags: 7

i need to set theme setting programmatically. I use `mothership` theme.
So for example:

```
$type = theme_get_setting('mothership_classes_view');
dpm($type);
//dpm displays 1 - so this setting is checked
//i need to uncheck it, set it to 0
```

i can't find a function to do this, what is the best way to set it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in the [code of `theme_get_settings()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_get_setting/7), if data is not in cache, it's obtained from variables:

```
// Get the saved global settings from the database.
$cache[$theme] = array_merge($cache[$theme], variable_get('theme_settings', array()));

if ($theme) {
  // Get the saved theme-specific settings from the database.
  $cache[$theme] = array_merge($cache[$theme], variable_get('theme_' . $theme . '_settings', array()));
```

So usually when you need to change them from code, you will need to use good old [`variable_set()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7). And don't forget to clear the cache.

Answer (score 5):

The actual answer is this:

```
// Get the settings
$mothership_settings = variable_get('theme_mothership_settings', array());

// Set the variable
$mothership_settings['mothership_classes_view'] = 0;

// Save our settings
variable_set('theme_mothership_settings', $mothership_settings);
```

This is perfect for an update hook to run, and doesn't seem to (in my case) need a cache clear afterwards.

This can be abstracted to any theme, Drupal stores the settings in the theme_THEMENAME_settings variable. As Pierre mentions, you can also do this in the .info file of the theme but this is only a good idea when you are extending a base theme (as you don't want to overwrite contrib .info files).

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the default value for a theme setting fron the theme .info file.

```
settings[mothership_classes_view] = foo
```