# How to programmatically disable Global Theme Settings?

Tags: 7, forms, theming, installation-profiles

I am trying to programmatically disable `logo` and `site name`. I have seen some variables for these set in ***modules/system/system.admin.inc*** but haven't been able to disable them through my profile installer settings.

What is the proper way to disable them? I looked around the internet but found no one has really looked into this issue.

[image: global theme settings]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/91067/how-to-set-theme-setting) for a related question.

The theme settings are not individually saved as variables. They are all in a single variable, whose name depends on your theme. For example, if your theme name is `mytheme`, the variable name will be `theme_mytheme_settings`.

You can disable the logo and name like this:

```
$my_settings = variable_get('theme_mytheme_settings', array());
$my_settings['toggle_logo'] = 0;
$my_settings['toggle_name'] = 0;
variable_set('theme_mytheme_settings', $my_settings);
```

You can also disable settings by means of the `features` key in the `.info` file for your theme. The defaults are:

```
features[] = logo
features[] = name
features[] = slogan
features[] = node_user_picture
features[] = comment_user_picture
features[] = comment_user_verification
features[] = favicon
features[] = main_menu
features[] = secondary_menu
```

If you don't specify any of these, all are enabled. If you specify some, only the ones you specify are enabled. So if you wanted to hide logo and site name, you would put this in your `.info` file:

```
; features[] = logo
; features[] = name
features[] = slogan
features[] = node_user_picture
features[] = comment_user_picture
features[] = comment_user_verification
features[] = favicon
features[] = main_menu
features[] = secondary_menu
```

See the [theme settings documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/theme-settings) for more info. You need to be careful with this depending on what theme you are using. If you're overriding a base theme, these are the keys, but a contributed or custom theme might have different keys.