# Set value to specific custom theme setting

Tags: 8

I noticed that I can get a specific theme setting like so

```
theme_get_setting('myvar','mytheme');
```

but I don't see a way of actually setting a setting. Something along the lines of

theme_set_value('myvar','mytheme','value');
I looked at the functions available to me here https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/8.2.x
but I didn't see anything specific to my needs.

I do see there's already a question asking the same thing here
[How to set theme setting](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/91067/how-to-set-theme-setting)
but that is for Drupal 7 and I'm using 8.

Is there a quick way to set the value of a specific theme setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal 8 use configuration to store configuration settings. You can follow [document](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/defining-and-using-your-own-configuration-in-drupal-8). And snippet code to set new value for custom theme(replace theme_name with your theme name).

```
$config = \Drupal::service('config.factory')->getEditable('theme_name.settings');
$config->set('variable', 'value')->save();
```